# show if comment is in moderation

Tags: comments, moderation

How to display a moderation-message with a comment after posting a comment.

The workflow should be:

- post a comment
- wp thinks this one has to be moderated
- user sees his comment with a messe like "thx but you cannot see it since its in moderation"
- stretchgoal: this message should be visible every time the users visits (cookie?)
- the messages disapears when the comment gets deleted or approved

Is there a way to do this?
Thanks

ps: this is a crosspost from http://getsatisfaction.com/wordpress_snippets/topics/show_if_comment_is_in_moderation

Answer (score 4):

use the follow var: $comment->comment_approved and check for the value

```
<?php if (0 == $comment->comment_approved) { ?>
       <em><?php _e('Your comment must approved.', FB_BASIS_TEXTDOMAIN) ?></em>
<?php } ?>
```

code example: http://code.google.com/p/wp-basis-theme/source/browse/trunk/basis/comments.php

Comment: How can you custom tailor this message to only the person who created the comment? I have a problem right now where the cookie is not being set when a comment is being created and I am not sure why.

Comment: You should create a new question to get a solid answer. Also the hint, is the user logged in or not, then you have only his cookie to identifier.